# Finding different rows between Pandas dataframes, while preserving all original data from one df

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following actual data:

```
actual.code actual.distance
a             1
c             6
e             10
```

And also the following interpolated data for all observations:

```
interpolated.code   interpolated.distance
   a                     2
   b                     4
   c                     7
   d                     4
   e                     9
   f                     1
```

And I want the following output:

```
 output.code    output.distance
     a                 1
     b                 4
     c                 6
     d                 4
     e                 10
     f                 1
```

So for any rows where I don't have the actual data, I want to use the interpolated data. I tried an inner join but that didn't seem to work, as I want to keep all observations from the first dataframe, and only use data from the second if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A long version is to use `merge` while keeping the indicator in the result, and then then replace the `interpolated.distance` with `actual.distance` based on the indicator:

```
df_merge = df1.merge(df2, left_on="actual.code", right_on="interpolated.code", how="right", indicator=True)
df_merge["interpolated.distance"] = df_merge["interpolated.distance"].where(df_merge["_merge"] != "both", df_merge["actual.distance"]) 
df_merge.drop(["actual.code", "actual.distance", "_merge"], axis=1).sort_values("interpolated.code")

# interpolated.code interpolated.distance
#0          a                  1.0
#3          b                  4.0
#1          c                  6.0
#4          d                  4.0
#2          e                 10.0
#5          f                  1.0
```

---

Or another option, you can use `combine_first()` with `df1` as the calling object which will be prioritized when the values are picked up, Basically set the codes from both data frames as index, and combine the distance with `actual.distance` as the calling object, this will prioritize the values from actual.distance if the codes match:

```
(df1.set_index("actual.code")["actual.distance"]
 .combine_first(df2.set_index("interpolated.code")["interpolated.distance"])
 .rename_axis("output.code").rename("output.distance").reset_index())

#output.code    output.distance
#0     a              1.0
#1     b              4.0
#2     c              6.0
#3     d              4.0
#4     e             10.0
#5     f              1.0
```

Comment: `df.fillna(df1)` allows to fill `NaN` with df1 when `df1` is aligned with `df`. How to fill df2 with df1 when index and columns are aligned?

Comment: `fillna()` works if you want to replace the missing values in one series/data frame with another one. Here both data frames don't have missing values, it is just trying to prioritize values based on index and columns matching. So I would not think `fillna` works in this case.